# Seeing up/downvote count on Meta

Tags: support, meta, votes

A day or two ago, I was able to see upvote- and downvote-counts here on meta. That Feature is gone now.

Was it a bug that it was available or is it a bug that it is missing now?

Comment: FAQ says you need 750 rep. So probably a bug earlier...

Comment: @Aryabhata Thought the same, but wanted it confirmed by someone. Maybe it has something to do with the transition to open beta, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reputation required to enable different privilege (such as viewing vote counts) increases when the site moves from private beta to public beta. It now [requires 750 reputation to see vote counts, both on the main site and here on meta](https://cs.stackexchange.com/privileges/established-user). It previously required only 100.

You can see the full list of reputation requirements at different stages in [this post on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared).

Comment: Aaahhh, that explains a lot. Okay, thanks.

Comment: Excellent answer!